# Как определить и вывести пользователей, которые online?

Tags: mysql

Как вывести пользователей которые онлайн, в таблице `user` есть поля `id`, `login`, `last_visit`?

Пробовал так, но не получается

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `last_visit` < (NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

Comment: А что и как пишется в `last_visit`? Туда данные может попадают когда игрок разлогинился или через полчаса, после совершения последних действий. И timezone у того, что туда пишется какой? Туда может по UTC пишутся данные, а вы по локальному времени смотрите

Comment: в last_visit пишу тип timestamp     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP значение передается NOW()

Comment: и когда это пишется? все это должно быть в задаче, чтобы не пришлось перечитывать все комментарии (их может быть много)

Comment: @ZOymyng будет лучше если Вы выложите вашу таблицу и несколько записей на sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас получаете тех, кто более 15 минут не был в онлайне. Поменяйте оператор сравнения:

```
`last_visit` > (NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

Будет работать при условии, что `last_visit` правильно обновляется. Например, на любое действие юзера выполнять.

```
UPDATE user SET last_visit = NOW() WHERE id = [id_пользователя]
```

Comment: но чтобы работало надо сделатьтак же? добавьте код обновления этого самого поля на значение mysql-функции NOW().

Comment: а по подробней можно, куда это вставить и как именно?

Comment: Я думаю вам виднее. Это ваш код? Или вы делаете запросы из чужой базы? Если ваш код, то как вам написали, если пользователь проявляет активность (я не знаю как это у вас в коде описывается) делайте апдейт.

Comment: мой, а вообще стандартных решений нету для таких случаев?

Comment: Как вы себе это представляете? У вас есть код который реализует работу системы, описана система авторизации, вы делаете запись в таблицу после авторизации, на каждое действие пользователя (нажал на кнопку, сделал ещё что то) вы обновляете дату и время, это значит пользователь все ещё активен.